# Solidity - Sell function not working

Tags: web3js, ether, myetherwallet, etherscan

I have my contract and people can buy my tokens via web3 and MetaMask. Now when I try to execute sell() function throw an exception and always Etherscan says Failed.

I set to sell and buy prices on my contract.

Here is my sell function:

```
/// @notice Sell `amount` tokens to contract
/// @param amount amount of tokens to be sold
function sell(uint256 amount) public {
    require(address(this).balance >= amount * sellPrice);      // checks if the contract has enough ether to buy
    _transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);              // makes the transfers
    msg.sender.transfer(amount * sellPrice);          // sends ether to the seller. It's important to do this last to avoid recursion attacks
}
```

I don't know what more I have to do. Does someone have any idea to help me?

UPDATE:
Full code: https://pastebin.com/eBYC77GV.

UPDATE2:
Etherscan Report: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1213ca9540b8b7c0bd34f09dac906906772416a31e3b01559d0c0a3c05582a19

Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of sellPrice?

Comment: With the little informations we have, I guess you maybe set a wrong `sellPrice`. `1000000000000000 * sellPrice` being superior to the balance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sell price value is scaled up ie `amount * (sellPrice * (10**18))` then you'll have a massively large value, so you'll need to divide the result by `10**18`.  Say for example sellPrice is meant to be 100 tokens in units of wei, tha would be `100 * (10**18)`. If you pass in a value for amount that is also  in units of wei, you'll have an even larger number:

`(amount * (10**18)) * (sellPrice * (10**18))`

You have a few options here, you can either set sellPrice to not be scaled up to units of wei `100`, not `100 * (10**18)`. Or if you prefer to keep everything in units of wei, you can simply divide your final result by `10**18`. Alternatively, you can keep sellPrice in units of wei, and what you pass in for `amount` don't convert to units of 
u

Comment: You say something like this?: amount * (sellPrice * 10 ** 18) / 10**18

Comment: Yup you've got it!

Comment: Its working! Thank you! But I have a bug when I put 1 on the amount the contract discount from my account 0.001 and not 1 token. Any idea?

Comment: No problem! Try passing in 100 I suspect that would fix that issue. However it sounds like you might be dividing an extra time since you end up with 0.001 instead of 1